# Selecting WMS backdrop in QGIS print composer?

Tags: qgis, wms, sql, parameters

I have a WMS service from Geoserver which is controlled by a parameter ([SQL params](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/data/database/sqlview.html)). This means that the following string is added to the getmap-request to Geoserver:

```
viewparams=objectid:11
```

With this I will get a tailored wms-map for a category of objects. I am thinking of creating an atlas based on the a control table which holds information about the objectid, plate name, description and more.

```
platenumber  objectid  objectname   description
1            10        Polar bears  This map shows where to find polar bears.
2            20        Crows        This map shows where to find crows.
3            55        Dragons      This map shows where to find dragons.
```

Is it possible to dynamically (through the atlas) control the wms getmap string?